# group rows into a list in pyspark

Tags: group-by, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe having a structure similar to the following table

```
 **col1** **col2**

    A       1
    B       2
    A       3
    B       4
    C       1
    A       2
```

I want it to be grouped on col1 and create a list of values on col2. Following should be my output

```
**col1**    **list**
   A        [1,3,2]
   B        [2, 4]
   C         [1]
```

Can someone point me to any references?

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job:

```
df.groupBy($"col1").agg( collect_list($"col2") )
```